# how to pass dynamic arguments in Relay modern?

Tags: reactjs, relaymodern

I have specific requirement in Relay-Modern to pass current date as arguments. From which i understand it's not possible in Relay-Modern as we can not write any code in initialVariables(was part of Relay Classic Api) as this step is now shifted to build Time. So i am using QueryRenderer at parent level to pass variables down to component at the time of mount.It worked well when i used this approach for 1 component. But now i got into another issue in which i have two component which shows same data but using different variables.

Current Widget

**Shows 10 Records based on current time**

Delayed Widget

**Shows 20 records starting currentTime - 30 mins**

Both components can have common data.

When i am declaring their own variables at parent level it is failing at compile time :

`Expected all fields on the same parent with the name or alias events to have the same name and arguments`

What would be correct approach to resolve these issues in Relay-Modern?

P.S.: I know hackyway of doing it to get big data set in both components or parent level then have logic in JS to filter and show on UI.